# How can I fix missing conf files when using shadowJar and Scala dependencies?

Tags: scala, gradle, dependency-management, typesafe-config, shadowjar

Writing this for users who have future issues like me. Libraries that are built on the Typesafe config typically use their own `reference.conf` files and refer to certain configuration keys. When building a fat JAR using the Gradle `shadowJAR` plugin, these files aren't included.

Dependencies like Spray and Akka throw errors when the fat JAR attempts to run. Errors look like:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'spray'
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka'
```

How to fix this? Check the answer below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The resulting fix was to add the following to the `build.gradle` file:

```
shadowJar {
  transform(com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer) {
    resource = 'reference.conf'
  }
}
```

Solution was found here:http://www.sureshpw.com/2015/10/building-akka-bundle-with-all.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
  shadowJar {
    append('reference.conf')
  }
```

See [Controlling JAR Content Merging](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/merging/#merging-service-descriptor-files)